# Python: From 2 Strings Delete Dissimilar Lines

Tags: python, string

I'm using Python to look at String A and String B.

String A only contains words (with \n newline character as each word is on its own line).

Next, I have String B, which contains lots of words, some which are found in String A and others that are not. I would like to only retain words in String B that are also in String A. The only problem here is that there are other characters after the words in String B that I would also like to retain.

Example:

```
String_A='apple/nbanana/nkiwi/npear'
String_B='cow|0.0|0.25|apple|0.0|0.99|pig|0.0|horse|0.2|banana|0.0|dog|0.2|kiwi|0.25|'
```

I would like String_C to have an end format of:

```
String_C='apple|0.0|0.99|banana|0.0|kiwi|0.25|'
```

Please see if you can assist! Thanks.

Comment: Your desired output is ambiguous. What if the words contain numbers or |s?

Comment: @Antimony: the words will never contain a number or character, from my knowledge of the text files I have. the only special characters are the '|' and '.' symbols.

Comment: @Blender: I began with python.re but couldn't find a useful way that both deletes undesired characters but retains the same characters if they fall after a desired word.

Answer (score 0):

If there's always exactly two groups after each word in StringB you can do the following

```
def foo(stringA, stringB):
    sawords = frozenset(stringA.split('\n'))
    sbparts = stringB.split('|')
    sbgroups = [sbparts[i:i+3] for i in range(len(sbparts))[::3]]
    filtered = [group for group in sbgroups if group[0] in sawords]
    return '|'.join(itertools.chain(*filtered))
```

Comment: unfortunately there are not always two groups after each word in String_B

Comment: Well then the problem is ill posed. Are the extra characters always going to be numerical?

Comment: characters in between words will always be of the type numerical or special characters in ('|','.','-'). no further deviation from this. apologies if the example code failed to catch these nuances.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the better implementation, but it worked

```
a = String_A.split('\n')
b = String_B.split('|')
c = []
for i in a:
    try:
        found = b.index(i)
        c.append(b[found])
        found += 1
        while found < len(b) and all(map(str.isdigit, (i for i in b[found] if i != '.-'))):
            c.append(b[found])
            found += 1
    except ValueError:
        pass
c = '|'.join(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach ignores the name fields, insomuch as they can contain decimals, "-", and ".", so long as it also contains something else.  Instead, this function uses the re module to test for the non-name fields. You can modify the regex if you want to allow for other characters in the non-name fields.  I made a couple of changes to String_B to check for the other, non-decimal character types.

```
import re
import itertools

def filter_strings(stra, strb):
    splita = stra.split("\n")
    splitb = strb.split("|")
    bnestlist = []
    sublist = []

    for segment in splitb:
        if re.match("[\d\.-]+", segment):
            sublist.append(segment)
        else:
            if sublist: bnestlist.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
            sublist.append(segment)

    filtered = [group for group in bnestlist if group[0] in splita]
    return "|".join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(filtered))
```

Example:

```
>>> String_A='apple\nbanana\nkiwi\npear'
>>> String_B='cow|0.0|0.25|apple|0.0|-0.99|pig|0.0|horse|0.2|banana|0.0|dog|0.2|kiwi|0.25|'
>>> result = filter_strings(String_A, String_B)
>>> print(result)
apple|0.0|-0.99|banana|0.0|kiwi|0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'|'.join([elem for elem in String_A.split('/') if elem in String_B.split('|')])
```